# How to create a dataframe from scratch?

Tags: r, dataframe

[image][image]Just wanted to know how to create a dataframe in R the attached format and then Graph it in R in the attached graph form.

sorry, I could not figure out a better way than attaching pics of what exactly I wanted to achieve.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The data.frame**

```
data <- data.frame(
  type = c("BMW", "TOYOTA", "HONDA"),
  NC   = 100,
  SC   = 200,
  NY   = 150
)
```

**Graphing**

```
library(ggplot) # Install first
library(data.table) # Install first
# Reshape data
data_melted <- melt(data, id.vars = "type")

# Now create the actual plot
ggplot(data_melted, aes(x = type, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It will probably take a long time for me to make sense out of it. Let me go and disect this a bit and hopefully I can make sense out of it. I will be back with questions? Thanks a ton!

Comment: The first thing is to master the `data.frame` - but in order to do that you should start with vectors and data types. `data.frames` are a collection of vectors that can have different types but have the same length.

Comment: @user1079898 an important thing you will encounter is recycling. R fills in (identical) values to make sure number of rows matches for all variables (columns).

Comment: hi tried doing this before I go into the high level stuff, but it is not working. Right now I am just ceating a matrix and filling it up using for loop and some conditions.

Comment: mat <- matrix(, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
row.names(mat) <- c("nc","sc","ny")
col.names(mat) <- c("BMW","Toyota","Honda")


for(row in 1:nrow(mat)) {
    for(col in 1:ncol(mat)) {
        
        if(colnames(mat1)[1] == "nc"){

           mat[row,col]=0

           }
     else {mat[row,col]=12}
     }

}

Comment: @user1079898 Your code looks like it's getting close but if you think you know where the whole in your understanding is it's best ask a seperate question with an example of what you've tried and what you want to achieve..